# Android - App's shortcut on homescreen doesn't update on new install

Tags: android, icons, synchronization

We have a v1 (version 1) of a application on Google Play and a v2 in which we have changed the app's launch icon. To test the change, we download v1 from Play and then we install v2 over it. When we install v1, a shortcut of the app is created in the phone's home screen. This is due to the fact that the "Auto-Add widgets" option is checked in the Google Play's Settings. 
The problem appears when we install v2 over v1. At the update, the v2's icon is correctly updated in the menu(the new icon is displayed), but the shortcut in the home screen has the old icon.

This problem doesn't appear if the user installs v1 of the app, creates the shortcut on the home screen and then updates to v2, so my guess is that the cause is related to the fact that the shortcut is automatically created (through code or through the "Auto-Add widgets").

My question is what can be done to prevent the shortcut of being created on the home screen (code-wise). I know there is code for creating shortcuts, but is there code for preventing them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you signing the .apk for v2 with the same Production cert that v1 is signed with?

Comment: Yes, of course. I used the same keystore. I don't think it would work updating otherwise :P